# Can't open perl script "./script.pl": Permission denied

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I get the error when trying to run a script. The script previously worked, but I edited one part of the code in Notepad++ (I change a ">" to a "<" ).

Any help would be appreciated! I was wondering whether it was a formatting issue after editing and saving in Notepad++ or if somehow my edit breaks the script.

(I'm using Ubuntu for Windows)

I've tried using sudo & sudo chmod a+x before the script, but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: How do you run the script? What are all the permissions of the file?

Comment: What do you see if you type `ls -l ./script.pl`?

Comment: I get: -r--r--r-- 1 [username] [username] 12466

Comment: You must also give permissions to the directory that contains the script: `chmod a+rwx dirname`. I've had this problem a few times myself on Ubuntu 14.04. This is why I no longer make dirs on a Ubuntu box via the Windows mapped drive and Windows File Explorer, it doesn't get the permissions right. I always make new dirs in Ubuntu via the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that `perl` is unable to read the contents of the file `script.pl`.

Since it is not clear who the script's owner is, you may give read permission to everyone using the following, `sudo chmod a=rx path/to/script.pl`.

Comment: I tried that, and now I get the message: -bash: ./script.pl: Permission denied

Comment: @Leon I've updated the command. Can you please try with the updated one?

Comment: Hang on, I did sudo chmod a+x before the script again and now it works OK - so I think your suggestion must have fixed my problem! Thanks!.

Comment: Ah yes. The app doesn't support post deletion (regardless of reputation).